# How to check whether user selected item from spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have an activity which contain spinner that has some list of items and I have a button named as "submit",first time submit button becomes disable it will be enable only after user select item from spinner if not selected the submit remain disable,for this I have to make condition on button click .How can I do that
code:-

```
m_OperatorSpinner = (Spinner) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.operator_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, CRechargeOperatorList.item);
    m_OperatorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_OperatorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            COperatorStorage operatorName = CRechargeOperatorList.item[position];
            selectedOperatorCode = operatorName.code;
            Log.e(TAG, "Operator code:-" + selectedOperatorCode);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
public void checkforEmpty() {
    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        if (m_szMobileNumber.length() == 13) {
            if (m_szAmount.length() != 0) {
                if (selectedOperatorCode!=null){
                    m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(true);
                    m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
                    m_SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            proceedToRecharge(v);
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
                    m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
                }

            } else {
                m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
                m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
            }
        } else {
            m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
            m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
        }
    } else {
        try {
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No Internet Connection Available", getActivity());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
        m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for position and you just test on position:

Example:

```
if(position==1){
   //what to do here
}else if(position==2){
   //what to do here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set some Boolean flag true in onItemSelected and enable submit button according to state of flag.

```
boolean isItemSelected ;

    m_OperatorSpinner = (Spinner) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.operator_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, CRechargeOperatorList.item);
        m_OperatorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        m_OperatorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                COperatorStorage operatorName = CRechargeOperatorList.item[position];
                selectedOperatorCode = operatorName.code;
                Log.e(TAG, "Operator code:-" + selectedOperatorCode);
    if(position!=0){
    isItemSelected = true;
}else{
isItemSelected =false;
}

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        public void checkforEmpty() {
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                if ((m_szMobileNumber.length() == 13) &&
                     (m_szAmount.length() != 0) &&(selectedOperatorCode!=null) && isItemSelected ){
                            m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(true);
                            m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
                            m_SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    proceedToRecharge(v);
                                }
                            });
                        }else {
                            m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
                            m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
                        }

                    } else {
                        m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                try {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No Internet Connection Available", getActivity());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                m_SubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
                m_SubmitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
            }
        }
```

Comment: its not working .....I have to detect spinner when user select item on position ==0 then submit button remain disable and when select item on position 1 then becomes enable .........................